# Dynamically update fyne tree widget

Tags: go, fyne

need help to update a Tree widget at runtime, as suggested here [fyne issue](https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne/issues/2167#issuecomment-819545352) seems that using Refresh() function on the widget it will sync the data changes stored in the `list` map, here is the code:

```golang
package main

//______________________________________________________________________________

import (
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/layout"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"

    dbg "github.com/fatih/color"
)

//______________________________________________________________________________

var content *fyne.Container
var tree *widget.Tree
var list map[string][]string

//______________________________________________________________________________

func main() {
    myApp := app.New()
    myWindow := myApp.NewWindow("List")
    makeTree()
    top := widget.NewLabel("Items' list::")
    bottom := widget.NewButton("Update list", updateList)
    content = container.New(layout.NewBorderLayout(top, bottom, nil, nil),
        top,
        tree,
        bottom,
    )

    myWindow.SetContent(content)
    myWindow.Resize(fyne.NewSize(480, 600))
    myWindow.ShowAndRun()
}

//______________________________________________________________________________

func makeTree() {
    list = map[string][]string{
        "":  {"A"},
        "A": {"B", "D"},
        "B": {"C"},
        "C": {"abc"},
        "D": {"E"},
        "E": {"F", "G"},
    }

    tree = widget.NewTreeWithStrings(list)
    tree.OnSelected = func(id string) {
        dbg.Green("Tree node selected: %s", id)
    }
    tree.OnUnselected = func(id string) {
        dbg.Green("Tree node unselected: %s", id)
    }

    tree.OpenAllBranches()
}

//______________________________________________________________________________

func updateList() {
    dbg.Green("UpdateList")

    list = map[string][]string{
        "":  {"A"},
        "A": {"B"},
        "B": {"C"},
    }

    tree.Refresh()
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NewTreeWithStrings` is a static helper function, so does not really update the way you want.
If you can use `NewTree` then you can point to your data structure and it will auto update.

Comment: We use one for fyne_demo navigation https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne/blob/9b5a176fe1dc80beae72a3074d0d5cd2b409637c/cmd/fyne_demo/main.go#L135